# Use section but hide the content in the file and keep it in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

In my document I insert a pdf page just after a `\section*{Annex}`and I'm able to add it in the `\tableofcontents` with this `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Annex}` but I would like to hide it from the document and keep it in the Table of content.
Is that possible?

Comment: In "hide it" and "keep it" what exactly is "it"?

Comment: "it" is the section name, I re-explain. I want to create a section that we will call Conclusion for example and display it only in the table of contents, not in the document while keeping the link between them.

I want that when I click on Conclusion in the table of contents it takes me to the part where my conclusion is but whitout title "conclusion" at the beginning of this part.

I hope it's clearer now. Maybe I'm looking for the impossible xD. ty anyways

Answer (score 1):

It seems rather obvious, so I may misunderstand, but just omit the `\section*` command, using only `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Annex}` (note "section" rather than "part"). Use `\clearpage` to ensure the toc entry points to the Annex page, rather than the page before it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First}
hello first section
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Annex}
\includepdf[pages=1]{xyz.pdf}
\end{document}
```

About pdfpages in the table of contents: you may want to use `\includegraphics` instead of `\includepdf` so the page number on the page matches the table of contents, unless the included pdf happens to have the same page number on it.